# How to get Active Directory Attributes not represented by the UserPrincipal class

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

What I mean is that right now I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and if I use UserPrincipal class I only see the Name, Middle Name, etc

so in my codes it like

```
UserPrincipal myUser = new UserPrincipal(pc);
myUser.Name = "aaaaaa";
myUser.SamAccountName = "aaaaaaa";
.
.
.
.
myUser.Save();
```

How would I see the attribute like mobile or info?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The proper way of doing it is by using `PrincipalExtensions` where you extend the `Principal` you are after and use the methods `ExtensionSet` and `ExtensionGet` as explained [here](http://macaalay.com/2010/10/14/how-to-use-ad-attributes-not-represented-in-userprincipal-groupprincipal-and-computerprincipal/).

Answer (score 36):

In this case, you need to go one level deeper - back into the bowels of `DirectoryEntry` - by grabbing it from the user principal:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = myUser.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)
{
    if (de != null)
    {
        // Go for those attributes and do what you need to do...
        var mobile = de.Properties["mobile"].Value as string;
        var info = de.Properties["info"].Value as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine as a quick fix, but I am trying to avoid using Directory Entry. Thanks for the help

Comment: Amazed this got so many upvotes, as it doesn't show how to implement the `de` object to get the properties.

Comment: Here is an example to get the Common-Name `de.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: I like this answer much more than the accepted answer. This is a lot less involved and gets you the information you need beautifully.

Comment: If I want to pull some fields under  "Organization" tab, how do I find the property names? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`up.Mobile` would be perfect, but unfortunately, there's no such method in the UserPrincipal class, so you have to switch to DirectoryEntry by calling `.GetUnderlyingObject()`.

```
static void GetUserMobile(PrincipalContext ctx, string userGuid)
{
    try
    {
        UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, userGuid);
        DirectoryEntry up_de = (DirectoryEntry)up.GetUnderlyingObject();
        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(up_de);
        deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");
        SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
        if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
        {
            ResultPropertyCollection rpc = results[0].Properties;
            foreach (string rp in rpc.PropertyNames)
            {
                if (rp == "mobile")
                    Console.WriteLine(rpc["mobile"][0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you load a property on `deSearch` that has an empty value in AD, it doesn't come back in the results set and the original code doesn't check for it not being there, so it throws the exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on that `Console.WriteLine` line.  I submitted an edit that should do the job.

Comment: Note, too, this should all be wrapped in a `try...catch`.  If a user is sent to this function that is no longer in AD, it will also get the exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the `DirectoryEntry` instantiation - corrected this in my edit, too.

Comment: Also, I don't even see "mobile" in the list of possible PropertyNames in the `rootSearch` of `results`.  There is `telephonenumber` that might actually be what the OP is looking for.  It is the same as "Phone" in the GUI form for a user in AD, but also, that is the same as `up.VoiceTelephoneNumber`, and so would not even require the `.GetUnderlyingObject()` call. But other properties likely would, so this to me, is the best solution to iterate through them all.

Comment: Why use `DirectorySearcher`? Using ***de.Properties*** ? `var mobile = de.Properties["mobile"].Value as string;`